# Can Verilog HDL realize what “#if ... #else ...” do in C？

Tags: verilog

I want to write a module with a parameter which decide which clock edge would be used. And I know I can use a selector to get clock or reversed clock, then use the posedge. I am just interest in how I can realize it in pre-compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`module myD #(parameter whichedge=0)
  (input wire clk,
    input wire a,
    output reg b);

generate
    if(whichedge == 0)
    begin
        always@(posedge clk)
            b <= a;
    end
    else
    begin
        always@(negedge clk)
            b <= a;
    end
endgenerate

endmodule`

Comment: Ooooooops, I'm sorry. I don't know how to make it like mcleod_ideafix's answer above.

Answer (score 0):

By using Verilog compiler directives (sort of preprocessor commands):

```
`define EDGE posedge

always @(`EDGE clk) begin
  ... stuff...
end
```

Or this way:

```
`define POSITIVE 0
`define NEGATIVE 1

`define EDGE `POSITIVE

`if (`EDGE==`POSITIVE)
always @(posedge clk) begin
`else
always @(negedge clk) begin
`endif
  ... stuff...
end
```

Haven't tested params and directives, but this may work too:

```
module #(parameter whichedge=0) ( // 0=posedge, 1=negedge
  input wire clk,
  input wire rst,
  ...
  ...
  )

`if (whichedge==0)
always @(posedge clk) begin
`else
always @(negedge clk) begin
`endif
  ... stuff ...
end
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But if I do not make mistake, there is only "\`fdef ... \`else ...“ in Verilog HDL（Error (10064): Verilog HDL Compiler Directive error at test.v(8): must use \`ifdef directive with \`else directive）. And your first two answer can not slove my problem which is one top-module instantiating one posedge and the other negedge. In addition, is there two kinds  of flip-flop in one FPGA chip or  it just reverse the clock if I use negedge, In the end, I found "generate" can do what I want in a rough way. `"genetate if ... else ..."`

Comment: @Hubert if you have a working solution you should post it as an answer, it may help some one else. Regarding FPGAs having negative and positive triggered flip-flops, I would expect they will have only one type but would invert the clock tree, ie place an inverter before the clk in, to reverse the triggering.